# In Dominion: Adventures, does the discarded Traveller have to be in hand, or can it have been played?

Tags: dominion, dominion-adventures

I've read the instructions three times, and I can't understand whether the Traveller card being discarded can have been played that turn, then discarded in the clean up phase, or whether it should still be in hand at the clean up phase, and discarded at that point to trade up to the next level of Traveller.

Secondly, does one need sufficient coins to trade up to the next level during their buy phase, or is trading up free, costing only the discarded card?

I understand that the discarded card should go back in its original pile, not in the Trash pile. I'm just unclear on those two points mentioned above.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [rulebook](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=1907), bottom of p5:

> When a player discards a Traveller **from play**, he may exchange
>   it for the card indicated.

Your hand is never considered to be "in play":

> "In play" - Action cards and Treasure cards played face-up to a play area are **in play** until they are
>   moved somewhere else—usually until they are discarded during a Clean-up phase.

So discarding it from your hand does not do anything; you **must** play it and then discard it from play at cleanup to trigger the exchange. You do not pay for the upgraded card - the upgraded version has a cost only because of the many cards like Remodel that care about a card's cost.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much for this clarification!

Comment: A minor note on the last sentence... there's 2 other reasons that the other cards have a cost. One is that it makes it easy to see the order of the cards, as the cost increases exactly from $2 to $6. The other is that it's better design-wise if stronger cards cost more; Donald has said that that's something he decided after things like Prizes had already been done.